# Purple screen which asks the option between windows and ubuntu not showing

Tags: dual-boot

After installing ubuntu, i removed the USB drive after pressing restart and now the purple screen is not showing. I am getting directly to windows.

Comment: Holding down SHIFT (Or ESC ?) while booting should bring you to the GRUB menu.

Comment: May be that grub has been installed on the wrong disk, i.e. not on the first disk that the system checks to boot. Check here on how to repair grub https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Which release number of Ubuntu is installed?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]